# E-Mail client for linux with painless creation of mailing lists from csv or spreadsheet files

Tags: linux, email-client

I am looking for an (good and stable) email client for linux which supports to create mailing lists directly from a csv or spreadsheet file as painless as possible.

Alternatively: If the mailing lists would be saved as plain text files, it would be easy enough to create them using for example emacs.

Would be also great if I could create a mailing list as follows:

Select multiple mails and then (for example via context menu) add all sender addresses to a specific mailing list or create a new one.

Regarding terminology: If I want to write a message to all people of a specific group, I just want to choose this group as address and don't want to include all addresses to the recipient list manually. So for example if the client allows to choose a specific address book as recipient instead of a "mailing list", this would be equally fine.

The client should support multiple accounts, imap and pop.

Would be nice to have also versatile and fast search capabilities to filter and find old mails.

I am currently using thunderbird, but creating mailing lists in bulk isn't fun. As described [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-create-and-use-mailing-lists-thunderbird) you have to import the addresses to an address book, and then drag and drop (in bulk) the addresses to an empty mailing list. However the drag and drop seems to work sometimes and sometimes not.

Note that I use thunderbird in maildir mode and want to move all my old mail to the new client.